# The $p$-torsion part of the Shafarevich-Tate group for a specific elliptic curve in the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E: y^2 + y = x^3 - x^2 - 10x - 20$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, it is known that its $E(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is finite and its Shafarevich-Tate group $\mathrm{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is trivial. Let $\mathbb{Q}_\infty/\mathbb{Q}$ be the (cyclotomic) $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the $n$-th layer $\mathbb{Q}_n/\mathbb{Q}$. Then I am hoping to show:

**Goal**: $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p} \mathrm{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p] > p^n - c$ for all $n$, where $c$ is some constant.

The purpose of this post is asking how to prove this.

**My attempts**: We consider the short exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow E(\mathbb{Q}_n) \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p \rightarrow \mathrm{Sel}(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p] \rightarrow \mathrm{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q})[p] \rightarrow 0.
$$

Then

$$
\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p} \mathrm{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p] = \dim_{\mathbb{F}_p} \mathrm{Sel}(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p] - \mathrm{rank}E(\mathbb{Q}_n).
$$

**We assume $E$ has good ordinary reduction at $p$**. Then we know from a corollary of Mazur's control theorem that $\mathrm{rank} E(\mathbb{Q}_n)$ is bounded from above by some constant $c$ as $n$ varies. So we have

$$
\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p} \mathrm{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p] \geq \dim_{\mathbb{F}_p} \mathrm{Sel}(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p] - c.
$$

Therefore a key is to compute $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p} \mathrm{Sel}(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p] \approx p^n$. This is where I got stuck, since there are two giant steps for me to go through:

1. The control theorem of Mazur said that there is a pseudo-isomorphism of $\Lambda$-modules
   $$
   \mathrm{Sel}(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p^{\infty}] \rightarrow \mathrm{Sel}(E/\mathbb{Q}_\infty)[p^{\infty}]^{\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}/\mathbb{Q}_n)}. 
   $$
   Actually I cannot see how to equip these objects with $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear structure since they are all "$p$-primary parts", not "$p$-torsion parts". I can see that the $\mu$-invariant is $1$ and $\lambda$-invariant is $0$ at $p=5$, but how do these lead to the computation of the $\mathbb{F}_p$-dimension?
2. There is still a gap between $\mathrm{Sel}(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p^{\infty}]$ and $\mathrm{Sel}(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p]$ that I am not able to go through.

So I got stuck here.

*Remark*: This is Exercise 4.5 in Ralph Greenberg's article *"Introduction to Iwasawa Theory for Elliptic Curves"*.

*Remark*: Another problem is that to use Mazur's control theorem, we assumed that $E$ is good ordinary at $p$. But **how to get the result for all the other primes**, since in the exercise, there is actually no assumption on the reduction type.

Comment: I’m not as knowledgeable in Iwasawa theory as I would like, but here’s a suggestion: does Mazur’s theorem tell us anything about the lengths of the kernel and cokernel of $f: Sel(E/\mathbb{Q}_n)[p^{\infty}] \rightarrow Sel(E/\mathbb{Q}_{\infty})[p^{\infty}]^{Gal(\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}/\mathbb{Q}_n)}$, and more precisely how they vary when $n$ changes? Then you could take the $p$-torsion on both sides of $f$ and hopefully control the difference of lengths… I have a vague recollection that $\mu=1$ implies some $p^n$-like terms in the length…

Comment: Is this (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9809206.pdf) what you’re working off? I don’t see any exercise 4.5 …

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you for your comments and I am so sorry for my late reply. I have been working on such exercises these days and found that indeed Mazur's control theorem should be applied, and following your hint, I somehow managed to solve the exercise by noting that (possibly) $$\mathrm{Sel}^{(p)}(E/\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}) = \mathrm{Sel}^{(p^{\infty})}(E/\mathbb{Q}_{\infty})[p].$$ Thank you for your hints!

Comment: @Aphelli And I am working on the Greenberg's note https://sites.math.washington.edu/~greenber/Park.ps obtained from his webpage https://sites.math.washington.edu/~greenber/research.html. I was suggested by my advisor to read this note first and solve all the exercises since it is more friendly to new learners than the one you linked above. (Though anyway, the note you linked is a must-read one.) Thank you for your great help again! :)